# apply sort to a pandas groupby operation

Tags: python, pandas

How do I apply sort to a pandas groupby operation? The command below returns an error saying that 'bool' object is not callable

```
import pandas as pd

df.groupby('cokey').sort('A')

cokey       A   B
11168155    18  56
11168155    0   18
11168155    56  96
11168156    96  152
11168156    0   96
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Normally the sort is performed on the groupby keys and as you've found out you can't call `sort` on a groupby object, what you could do is call `apply` and pass the `DataFrame.sort` function and pass the column as the kwarg param:

```
In [58]:

df.groupby('cokey').apply(pd.DataFrame.sort, 'A')
Out[58]:
               cokey   A    B
cokey                        
11168155 1  11168155   0   18
         0  11168155  18   56
         2  11168155  56   96
         3  11168155  96  152
```

Alternatively you could just sort the df prior to grouping:

```
df.sort('A').groupby('cokey')
```

**Update**

For version `0.17.0` and above `DataFrame.sort` is now deprecated see the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#changes-to-sorting-api), one should now use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html#pandas.DataFrame.sort_values):

```
df.groupby('cokey').apply(pd.DataFrame.sort_values, 'A')
```

Adding @xgdgsc 's answer in comments to here; in case you need to set ascending flag.

```
df.groupby('cokey').apply(pd.DataFrame.sort_values, 'A', ascending=False)
```

Comment: thanks! is there a way to reset_index() the resulting dataframe?

Comment: Subsequent operations get messed up with the multilevel indexing still present

Comment: Well you introduce another level of indexing by adding this sort criteria, you'd have to drop the superfluous indices after calling `reset_index` I'm afraid

Comment: In newer versions you should use pd.DataFrame.sort_values instead of pd.DataFrame.sort

Comment: @jcuypers sure will update, things change quickly so keeping all answer up to date is impossible but I always edit when prompted

Comment: @EdChum: Sure, no worries.  Any idea about speeding up and/or troubleshooting for 'large' datasets (100K-1M)? Sorting seems agonizingly slow.

Comment: Usually for large datasets you have to resort to use pytables/hdfs or dask I can't comment further without a real question but there are lots of questions on SO about this

Comment: How do you sort in descending order?

Comment: @user1700890 not at my dev machine so not sure try `df.groupby('cokey').apply(pd.DataFrame.sort_values, ('A', ascending=True))`

Comment: @EdChum it should be `df.groupby('cokey').apply(pd.DataFrame.sort_values , 'A', ascending=False)`

Comment: @xgdgsc it depends on what you want the OP wanted it sorted in this manner