# Pandas ordering based on column value

Tags: python, pandas, rows

I have a pandas dataframe like:

I have the data frame as like below one,

```
Input DataFrame
     id          ratio
 0   1           5.00%
 1   2           9.00%
 2   3           6.00%
 3   2           13.00%
 4   1           19.00%
 5   4           30.00%
 6   3           5.5%
 7   2           22.00%
```

How can I then group this like

```
         id          ratio
     0   1           5.00%
     4   1           19.00%
     6   3           5.5%
     2   3           6.00%
     1   2           9.00%
     3   2           13.00%
     7   2           22.00%
     5   4           30.00%
```

So essentially first looks at the ratio, takes the lowest for that value and groups the rest of the rows for which it has the same id. Then looks for the second lowest ratio and groups the rest of the ids again etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [apply sort to a pandas groupby operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29479357/apply-sort-to-a-pandas-groupby-operation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First convert your `ratio` column to numeric.

Then we get the lowest `rank` per group by using `Groupby`

Finally we sort based on `rank` and `numeric ratio`.

```
df['ratio_num'] = df['ratio'].str[:-1].astype(float).rank()
df['rank'] = df.groupby('id')['ratio_num'].transform('min')

df = df.sort_values(['rank', 'ratio_num']).drop(columns=['rank', 'ratio_num'])

   id   ratio
0   1   5.00%
1   1  19.00%
2   3    5.5%
3   3   6.00%
4   2   9.00%
5   2  13.00%
6   2  22.00%
7   4  30.00%
```

Answer (score 0):

With help of `pd.Categorical`:

```
d = {'id':[1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2],
     'ratio': ['5.00%', '9.00%', '6.00%', '13.00%', '19.00%', '30.00%', '5.5%', '22.00%']}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df['ratio_'] = df['ratio'].map(lambda x: float(x[:-1]))
df['id'] = pd.Categorical(df['id'], categories=df.sort_values(['id', 'ratio_']).groupby('id').head(1).sort_values(['ratio_', 'id'])['id'], ordered=True)
print(df.sort_values(['id', 'ratio_']).drop('ratio_', axis=1))
```

Prints:

```
  id   ratio
0  1   5.00%
4  1  19.00%
6  3    5.5%
2  3   6.00%
1  2   9.00%
3  2  13.00%
7  2  22.00%
5  4  30.00%
```