# How to get top n values from data frame columns?

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame as below

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame(
  {
    'rating': [5.0,4.5,3.0,2.5,4.0,4.5,5.0,3.0],
    'productname': ['s','v','r','n','k','a','q','w'],
    'category': [ 
      'mobile',
      'mobile',
      'mobile',
      'mobile',
      'laptop',
      'laptop',
      'laptop',
      'laptop'
    ]
  }
)
```

I am able to get the top rated product by below code:

```
df.loc[df.groupby('category')['rating'].idxmax(), :].reset_index()
```

My question is how to get the top 3 products in each category?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Top 3 rated products for each category

Comment: Can you perhaps edit your question and show what and how the expected output look like

Comment: Does this answer your question? [apply sort to a pandas groupby operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29479357/apply-sort-to-a-pandas-groupby-operation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`df.nlargest`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html):

```
>>> df
   rating productname category
0     5.0           s   mobile
1     4.5           v   mobile
2     3.0           r   mobile
3     2.5           n   mobile
4     4.0           k   laptop
5     4.5           a   laptop
6     5.0           q   laptop
7     3.0           w   laptop

>>> df.nlargest(3, 'rating')

   rating productname category
0     5.0           s   mobile
6     5.0           q   laptop
1     4.5           v   mobile

>>> df.nlargest(3, 'rating')['productname']

0    s
6    q
1    v
Name: productname, dtype: object
```

If you want top 3 for each category:

```
>>> df.groupby('category').apply(lambda x:x.nlargest(3, 'rating').drop('category',1))
  
            rating productname
category                      
laptop   6     5.0           q
         5     4.5           a
         4     4.0           k
mobile   0     5.0           s
         1     4.5           v
         2     3.0           r
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nlargest` for this purpose (no need for a sort) -

```
df.groupby(['category']).apply(lambda x:x.nlargest(3, 'rating'))
```

```
            rating productname category
category                               
laptop   6     5.0           q   laptop
         5     4.5           a   laptop
         4     4.0           k   laptop
mobile   0     5.0           s   mobile
         1     4.5           v   mobile
         2     3.0           r   mobile
```

Comment: Top 3 in each category